# Create and run java module

Tags: java

Here is my project structure:

```
⇒  tree
.
├── out
│   └── easytext
│       ├── javamodularity
│       │   └── easytext
│       │       └── Main.class
│       └── module-info.class
└── src
    └── easytext
        ├── javamodularity
        │   └── easytext
        │       └── Main.java
        └── module-info.java
```

Main.java:

```
package javamodularity.easytext;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("hello");
      System.in.read();
   }
}
```

module-info.java:

```
module easytext {
  requires java.base;
}
```

Build:

```
javac --module-source-path src -d out $(find . -name "*.java")
```

Trying to run:

```
cd out
java --module-path out -m easytext/javamodularity.easytext.Main

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module easytext not found
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: What if you don't do `cd out` and instead run the javac command from the above directory?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, no, I have checked it many times already )